# How to sign an assembly in .NET 1.1

Tags: .net, signing, .net-1.1, csc

So, for some horrible reason I need to compile a very old .NET 1.1 project. Compiling it is pretty easy, but I also need it to produce signed assemblies. I noticed that .NET 1.1 `csc.exe` is missing the `/keyfile` argument. How do I sign my assembly without this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [`AssemblyKeyFileAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblykeyfileattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it's basically equivalent to the command-line flag (as far as I'm aware) but less flexible due to being part of the source code, and it leaks the keyfile path information into the assembly itself. (Those are the reasons `/keyfile` is preferred.)

Comment: So .NET 1.1 lacked a command line way to do signing completely?

Comment: @Earlz: Yes, it had to be specified in the source.